# Open loop MOSFET switching for DC load

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet

I am designing a DC load circuit using an N-MOSFET. The goal is to drive/control the "load" digitally from an Arduino which only has analog output of 0 - 5VDC. A typical circuit consists of input reverence voltage (0-5VDC in our case) --> amplifier circuit implemented using an opamp --> MOSFET for switching high voltage/current.

I did a quick simulation of the circuit in LTspice to better understand the behaviour of each stage in the circuit and noticed that if I use the right size of Rsense (see  image below), I can feed 0-5 from the Arduino directly to the MOSFET gate to achieve output current range of 0 - 10A. This is achieved without any amplification stage which, some also call  a "regulator."

My question are:

1. What are the cons of implementing such an open loop circuit? Are there any "runaway" issues I can encounter?
2. What are the benifits of adding an opamp for regulation?

[image]

Comment: Vgs of mosfet changes with temperature too much what is a big disadvantage since mosfet in linear will heat up a much. Btw, you can implement a feedback using analog input on arduino by sensing resistor voltage with ADC or analog comparator.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický This is precisely what i was planning to do in the beginning as implementing a PID regulator in software will be far more convenient for me then tweeking and calibrating opamps but some of the comments on the forum claiming arduino to be too slow to respond to change in sense voltage scared me off.  This will be a 300 Watt load and i didn't wanna set my lab on fire.

Comment: [Most Arduinos don't have a real analog output.](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/) Check the link and see if yours does.  Most Arduinos only have a pulse width modulated DC output.  Your DC source may not play well with a pulsing load.

Comment: @JRE My Arduino UNO doesn't have Analog out which is why I am using MCP4151 10K Digital pot to generate 0-5VDC range controlled via I2C. This part of the circuit has been tested and works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two issues to consider.

- The gate threshold generally suffers quite a lot of variability, device-to-device and with temperature. Given where you've positioned the load you will have some feedback, but there will still be significant unpredictability in output for a given DAC output.
- You are running the FET in linear mode, so will be dissipating very significant amounts of power compared with a switcher configuration with inductors.  This is both inefficient, and will need to be dissipated with decent size heatsinks.

This may be okay for your app, but you should be aware of both issues.

Comment: You're right about point 1. My Vgs vs Ids test results do not match with the datasheet , which , as you suggested is due to temp factor.     In regards to the "switcher configuration", I just checked out some notes on Analog website and while the config looks intriguing, I'm afraid its a bit too sophisticated  to be implemented at this stage. I will save your comment and will probably implement it in version 2 which will have slightly bigger budget and faster controllers :).