# LTSpice modelling for a DC load

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, ltspice, powermosfet

I am new to LTSpice and am working on modelling a DC Load circuit using NMOS and an opamp. I wanted my simulation to be as accurate as possible so I downloaded the spice model for LM358 OPamp and MOSFET IRF450N directly from the manufacturer's website and imported them both to my LTSpice library.

Testing both devices independently seem to give expected results (image 1 and 2 attached). In MOSFET simulation, Rsense current is proportional to Vgs voltage however when I use OpAmp to drive the gate voltage, Isense is in mA! I've redrawn my circuit just be sure thre're no disconnected items. What am I doing wrong here? The circuit is dicto copy of hundreds of circuits available online.

[image: MOSFET IRF540N Simulation Vgs vs Ids]

[image: LM358N OpAMP]

[image: DC Load Circuit with OPAMP and MOSFET]

Comment: Well, you built a voltage divider with R1 and Rsense, so the opamp will not really regulate the output in a way to drive the current with the mosfet. What purpose should R1 fulfill?

Comment: @Arsenal I was just testing a scenario. I've also tested the circuit without R1 and the result is still the same. I will see if i can update the 3rd image to the one without R1.

Comment: Okay, then the issue you are facing is likely, that the LM358 is not able to provide a high enough output voltage to drive that mosfet. Have a look at the voltage of the opamp output, it is probably saturated at the maximum voltage. If you increase the supply of the opamp to say 15 V it could look different.

Comment: @Arsenal Thanks for your comment. When i try to increase the OpAmp voltage above  5VDC, LTSpice throws an error "Analysis: Time step too small; initial timepoint: trouble with node "u1:i_nn:7" ". Do you have any idea how to fix this problem ?

Comment: @Arsenal Okay I changed the simulator engine to "Alternate" in control panel and re run the simulation and now I can increase the Vss supply to opamp to 12VDC. Unfortunately the output current is still 40mA which is incorrect.

Comment: If you could provide links to the models I could check with those, I just hacked a circuit together with an AD8542 and IRF1010E (both are included in LTSpice) and that works as expected with a higher supply voltage. So either the LM358 is not suited (it's really not a good opamp) or the IRF540N is a strange mosfet or one of the models (probably LM358) is not good.

Comment: @Arsenal I really appreciate the help. Please use google drive link below to download the zip file containing all the model files as well as the library for the opamp and mosfet. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ATXPGq8GU4NftgfewmFNsD5EMR7qPDl0/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: @Arsenal  Not sure if it matters but I am using LTSpice 17.1.11 (x64). Again, Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @V.V.T - It was my understanding that if the noninverting is higher than inverting input, the output will be on the higher side !

Comment: Looked closer at your post. It seems you noticed a curious glitch

Comment: @V.V.T I believe I've narrowed down the issue to the IRF540N Model. Replacing it with built in library seem to be showing up to 5A current through Rsense. Let me try and reimport the model. I may've imported it incorrectly.

Comment: My apologies guys... The IRF model i imported was incorrect. I've fixed the model and will run completel simulation tomorrow and update the results... I think I've had enought of troubleshooting for today :).  Thanks a lot for your engagement.

Comment: Prashant, your power of persuasion is remarkable. You almost convinced me to try and capture your circuit and models into LTspice and re-evaluate my longtime experience with these components. Only multiple recitation of the Om Gam Ganatapaye Namaha mantra enabled me to regain my consciousness. So, +1 to mark your zeal, but, please, only use your powers with due circumspection! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution of this question can be found in schematics posted in thread blow:

[Open loop MOSFET switching for DC load](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/681534/open-loop-mosfet-switching-for-dc-load)